# Ubuntu 14.04 Does Not open

Tags: 14.04

Umm my ubuntu 14.04 update isnt working when i run *sudo startunity* it says Failed connecting to X server and it says giving up and also server aborting plz help with this error.

```
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...

_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.8.11 #1 SMP Tue May 26 16:21:19 PDT 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=42958537-1b1e-c440-a8a5-87ffafcba586/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=42958537-1b1e-c440-a8a5-87ffafcba586/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=16b083f40cd05ebecff1123920a312c58ab3d9f3 salt=8dfc3625f745a01b43a6b4ce00959fbf563d8eee918f37de9d7283e0a416a897" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=42958537-1b1e-c440-a8a5-87ffafcba586 add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic iTCO_vendor_support.vendorsupport=3  
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
        Before reporting problems, check 
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log", Time: Tue Jun  9 01:38:57 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7f8f64a47848]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x7f8f6489e000+0x1ad539) [0x7f8f64a4b539]
(EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f8f63797000+0x10340) [0x7f8f637a7340]
(EE) 3: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x7f8f6489e000+0xb57a6) [0x7f8f649537a6]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/Xorg (xf86BusProbe+0x9) [0x7f8f64927099]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/Xorg (InitOutput+0x74d) [0x7f8f649356fd]
(EE) 6: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x7f8f6489e000+0x59bab) [0x7f8f648f7bab]
(EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f8f621d7ec5]
(EE) 8: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x7f8f6489e000+0x451ee) [0x7f8f648e31ee]
(EE) 
(EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
http://www.java.com/en/download/ie_manual.jsp/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
chronos@localhost / $
```

Comment: Please list down all errors that appear

Comment: Posted all errors that appear

Comment: Did not work said  :                                              crosh> shell
chronos@localhost / $ sudo edit-chroot -a
precise
chronos@localhost / $ sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -n unity -u
/usr/local/chroots/unity does not exist; cannot update.
Valid chroots:
precise
chronos@localhost / $

Comment: read this: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Common-issues-and-reporting:

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Common-issues-and-reporting:

> Most issues can be fixed by downloading a fresh installer, and
>   updating your chroot:
>
> - Remove any existing installer from your Downloads folder.
> - Fetch a fresh installer: https://goo.gl/fd3zc
> - Open a crosh shell (Ctrl-Alt-T, then type shell)
> - Figure out the name of your chroot(s). If you do not know, sudo    edit-chroot -a (on recent enough crouton), or sudo ls
>     /usr/local/chroots will provide you with a list of chroot names.
> - Run an update: sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -n chrootname -u, where    chrootname is the name of your chroot.
> - Make sure there are no errors, then try starting your chroot again.